# ActivatedSnapshot creation order

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Take the following routing module as an example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first-admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/domain/first/first-admin/first-admin.module#FirstAdminModule'
    data: {module: 'first'}
  },
  {
    path: 'second-admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/domain/second/second-admin/second-admin.module#SecondAdminModule'
    data: {module: 'second'}
  }
}
```

The user requests /first-admin/** In my app component where ** is one of the child routes.

In the app-component I want to pickup the data associated with the ActivatedRoute but can't seem to figure this out, perhaps missing something.  I notice that when I dump the snapshot to the console at first it has 0 children and then has 1 child, I guess after the children are loaded.

The app component contains the router-outlet.  Per my understanding, when the app component loads the ActivatedRoute and Snapshot is the same as it is the first one?  Then when it loads the routable child component in the child route it creates a new Snapshot which will be the child of the first one and the current ActivatedSnapshot will reflect the current state.

Question - in my app component I tried subscribing to the data observable in the ActivatedRoute but I get only a null data object in the subscription.  In my app component how would I get the "first" module name which is part of the data?  It seems this data is attached to the Snapshot created by the child route.

Added these three lines in the ngOnInit in my app component:

```
console.log('looking at the activatedroute snapshot', 
     this.activatedRoute.snapshot);

console.log('looking at created copy of activated route', 
    {...this.activatedRoute});

console.log('looking at the activated route', this.activatedRoute);
```

Pic of issue here:

[image: Router state]

Answer (score 0):

Any object you define in the `data` attribute of a route definition is static and can only be accessed from the snapshot. The static nature of the `data` means an observable/subscription isn't needed, since the `data` will not change.

You access the data from the [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service that Angular provides.

An example of how to access the route data is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
    module = '';

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.module = this.route.snapshot.data['module'];

        console.log('snap');
        console.log(this.route.snapshot);
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['module']);
    }
}
```

I have tried to access route data via lazy loaded routes like you are, and it worked as expected. See below.

[image]

Comment: I had tried that, unfortunately it outputs undefined. I am thinking the data should be available on the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`, not sure why it isn't.  However, the data *is* available in the `ActivatedRoute` when I introspect it in the console, I am guessing because at the time the Snapshot is created the children are not yet loaded.

Comment: It works for me using `ActivatedRoute`, just like I coded it above. Based on your comment, it works for you too? I tried it with a lazy loaded route, and I was able to get the value of the module property in data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it.  I actually took a different approach to my problem using Guards.  When the guard fires I have all the info in the route data so was much easier.